# Cannot move out from behind mutable reference to Option

Tags: rust, reference, option-type

I've got a struct:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a mut Foo<'a>>,
    value: i32,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        if let Some(&mut parent) = self.parent {
            parent.bar();
        } else {
            self.value = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*self.parent.0` which is behind a mutable reference
 --> src/lib.rs:8:36
  |
8 |         if let Some(&mut parent) = self.parent {
  |                          ------    ^^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&self.parent`
  |                          |
  |                          data moved here
  |                          move occurs because `parent` has type `Foo<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `parent` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:9:13
  |
8 |         if let Some(&mut parent) = self.parent {
  |                          ------ help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut parent`
9 |             parent.bar();
  |             ^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

I've tried many variations of that line and can't get it to work. How can I do this?

Comment: FYI: `&'a mut Foo<'a>` is virtually always a mistake because it means the `Foo` is borrowed for its entire lifetime. If you have the same thing in real life code, you're probably going to have a bad time. See, for instance, [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](/q/32165917/3650362)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `if let` statement you are trying to destructure `self.parent` to obtain `parent`, and even obtain the `Foo` (itself, as a value) which is behind the stored reference.

You have to add an extra level of indirection to reference the `&mut Foo` that may or may not exist, without removing it from the `Option` if it exists.

```rust
if let Some(ref mut parent) = self.parent {
```

or

```rust
if let Some(parent) = self.parent.as_mut() {
```

The `parent` binding you obtain in both cases has type `&mut &'a mut Foo<'a>`, thus automatic-dereference will occur when calling `parent.bar()`.

nb: I use as a reminder « *`ref` on the left-hand-side of `=` is similar to `&` on the right-hand-side* », but here we want to add the `&` *inside* the `Option`, thus the usage of `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` depending on the expected mutability.

Comment: It's not necessary here, but `Option::as_deref_mut` can sometimes make code read more cleanly. In this case, by matching against an `Option<&mut Foo<'a>>` instead of `Option<&mut &'a mut Foo<'a>>`.